# i wrote a simple program for returning level of a node in tree using python but it returns none

Tags: python, class, tree, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data=data
    self.left=self.right=None
def insert(self,data):
    if self.data:
        if data<self.data:
            if self.left is None:
                self.left=Node(data)
            else:
                self.left.insert(data)
        elif data>self.data:
            if self.right is None:
                self.right=Node(data)
            else:
                self.right.insert(data)
def level(self,data,l):
    if data<self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return -1
        self.left.level(data,l+1)
    elif data>self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return -1
        self.right.level(data,l+1)
    elif self.data==data:
        print(l)
```

l=[8,7,6,5,10]
    root=Node(l.pop(0))
    for i in l:
    root.insert(i)
    pre(root)
l=root.level(10,1)
print(l)
expected out put is 2
but returns None

Comment: Did the solution worked?

Answer (score 0):

```
class Node:
  def __init__(self,data):
      self.data=data
      self.left=self.right=None

  def insert(self,data):
    if self.data:
      if data<self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            self.left=Node(data)
        else:
            self.left.insert(data)
      elif data>self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            self.right=Node(data)
        else:
            self.right.insert(data)

  def level(self,data,l):

    if data == self.data:
      level = l
    else:
      if data<self.data:
        if self.left is None:
            return -1
        level = self.left.level(data,l+1)
      elif data>self.data:
        if self.right is None:
            return -1
        level = self.right.level(data,l+1)

    return level

l=[8,7,6,5,10] 
root=Node(l.pop(0)) 
for i in l: 
  root.insert(i) 

print(root.level(8,1))
print(root.level(7,1))
print(root.level(6,1))
print(root.level(5,1))
print(root.level(10,1))
```

Your function should return something and also need to update level.